# how can I take the profit of the individual pages with google adsense or analytics api?

Tags: php, google-analytics, adsense-api

I would like to get the revenue from the google bees for every single item on my website to create a control panel on my website where I can see how much each item makes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AdSense Management API to [generate reports](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate) on your website's ads. You can specify [dimensions](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions#dimensions) to break down your data by (for example, using the AD_UNIT_ID dimension will generate a report with a row for each Ad Unit), and you can use [metrics](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions#metrics) to specify what data you want to retrieve (there are a number of metrics associated with revenue).

For a more detailed walkthrough, there are [several Reporting guides](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reporting/dimensions_metrics) that you might find useful.